Old comedy movie about characters living and interacting with a native tribe (likely in Africa)
It's been bothering me for quite a long time, any info would be appreciated. I remember watching a few scenes as a child, around the year 2000. It was likely an American movie. These could be different movies as well:

Someone asks for water, and is given a drop of water on a leaf. The person then pretends that drinking the drop was fulfilling.
Someone gets off a jeep, and exchanges a small mirror with a man for a piece of gold.
A man ties a parachute to the back of an ostrich and tries to fly.


You're looking for Crazy Safari (AKA The Gods Must Be Crazy III) from 1991.

Two guys, one of them a magician, are transporting an ancient chinese vampire who can only be controlled by a series of yellow tapes, and is the ancestor of the other guy. On the way, while flying over Africa, their plane stalls. And of all places, where do they land? That's right, in the village of the tribe of "The Gods Must Be Crazy".

All of the scenes that you described are there, though you forgot the hopping Chinese vampire. ;) Here's the trailer, where you can see the ostrich and parachute scene around 1:54:



